# Not able to draw rectangel over Qgraphics image

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, mouseevent, qgraphicsview

I am trying to draw rectangle over Qgraphics scene. I found many examples but none of them are working for me. The rectangle is drawn on the area not covered by Qgraphics view widget in the window but when i try over the image it is not working. I don't know why. One observation is over the Qgraphicsview mouse release event is not getting executed. But i could not solve the issue. Any help will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

The code I am working in as is below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'zoom_win_qt.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_zoom_win_qt(object):
    def setupUi(self, zoom_win_qt):
        zoom_win_qt.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("zoom_win_qt"))
        zoom_win_qt.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(zoom_win_qt)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 611, 431))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))        
        grview = self.graphicsView
        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('Koala.jpg')
        pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(420)
        scene.addPixmap(pixmap)        
        grview.setScene(scene)
        grview.show()        
        self.horizontalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 500, 160, 19))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalSlider"))
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 118, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressBar"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 500, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))    

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_clipped_zoom)  

        zoom_win_qt.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(zoom_win_qt)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        zoom_win_qt.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(zoom_win_qt)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        zoom_win_qt.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(zoom_win_qt)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(zoom_win_qt)

    def retranslateUi(self, zoom_win_qt):
        zoom_win_qt.setWindowTitle(_translate("zoom_win_qt", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("zoom_win_qt", "PushButton", None))



class Myrect(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_zoom_win_qt):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pos1 = [0,0]
        self.pos2 = [0,0]
        self.show()     


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        width = self.pos2[0]-self.pos1[0]
        height = self.pos2[1] - self.pos1[1]
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()        
        qp.begin(self)           
        qp.drawRect(self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1], width, height)        
        qp.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1] = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        print("clicked")

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.pos2[0], self.pos2[1] = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()
        print("released")
        self.update()            






def test_clipped_zoom():
     zoom_win_qt.hide()
     w.show()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Myrect()
    zoom_win_qt = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_zoom_win_qt()
    ui.setupUi(zoom_win_qt)
    zoom_win_qt.show()




    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi Deepa and welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend that you take a look at the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) docs so you can improve your chances of receiving an answer. In particular follow this advice 
`keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` is a widget to show a scene(`QGraphicsScene`), so the common thing is to add a rectangle to the scene (as if it were an actor), and not to paint. You are also painting in `Myrect` which is the widget where the other widgets are located so it is in the background, and the other widgets will cover the painting you do.

On the other hand it is not recommended to modify the class generated by Qt Designer, so I took the liberty to return it to its initial state

Returning to the starting point, to add a rectangle to the `QGraphicsScene` you must know the coordinates of those points in the coordinate system of the scene, so one way to do it is to use `eventFilter()`, this must filter the `GraphicsSceneMousePress` and `GraphicsSceneMouseRelease` events, these have the position and we can obtain it using the `scenePos()` method.

```
...
class Myrect(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_zoom_win_qt):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)   
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_clipped_zoom)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('Koala.jpg').scaledToHeight(420)
        self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)        
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene) 
        self.scene.installEventFilter(self)
        self.start = QtCore.QPointF()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.scene:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
                self.start = event.scenePos()
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseRelease:
                end = event.scenePos()
                self.scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.start, end))
                self.start = QtCore.QPointF()
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


def test_clipped_zoom():
     zoom_win_qt.hide()
     w.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Myrect()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Complete Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'zoom_win_qt.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_zoom_win_qt(object):
    def setupUi(self, zoom_win_qt):
        zoom_win_qt.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("zoom_win_qt"))
        zoom_win_qt.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(zoom_win_qt)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 611, 431))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))             
        self.horizontalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 500, 160, 19))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalSlider"))
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 118, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressBar"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 500, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))    
        zoom_win_qt.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(zoom_win_qt)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        zoom_win_qt.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(zoom_win_qt)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        zoom_win_qt.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(zoom_win_qt)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(zoom_win_qt)

    def retranslateUi(self, zoom_win_qt):
        zoom_win_qt.setWindowTitle(_translate("zoom_win_qt", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("zoom_win_qt", "PushButton", None))



class Myrect(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_zoom_win_qt):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)   
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(test_clipped_zoom)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('Koala.jpg').scaledToHeight(420)
        self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)        
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene) 
        self.scene.installEventFilter(self)
        self.start = QtCore.QPointF()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.scene:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMousePress:
                self.start = event.scenePos()
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.GraphicsSceneMouseRelease:
                end = event.scenePos()
                self.scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.start, end))
                self.start = QtCore.QPointF()
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


def test_clipped_zoom():
     zoom_win_qt.hide()
     w.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Myrect()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It is working as intended, thank you..I have one more related query.I want to place the rectangle over a video. I tried to read the video and store the frames in a folder.Now I want to read the folder sequentially and one any particular frame draw the rectangle and the rest  of the frames read should hold the rectangle. I am able to write the frames from a video but not able to read the using "os.listdi()". Can you help me with it.

Comment: @Deepa 
Create a new question showing what you have tried, and what are you failing and I will be happy to try to help you, on the other the best way to thank is to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it check the [tour]

Comment: Thank you for the help... I will post a new question with the work I did..